# Svarga py framework. Would you start learning a "one man band" framework?

Tags: python, web-frameworks

Would you start learning a "one man band" framework if someone you admired thought it had very good design choises? More so. Would you require the framework to have at least semi-good documentation before you thougt It would be worth investing your time in?

I read a blog post quite some time ago (can't find it now) and now I have summer break from my university. In the blog post the "skillful programmer" without giving reasons stated that he, thought the presentation of the author of the Svarga framework was the most interesting one in the last python conference he visited. Since I am also a thinking person I am aware of the fact that he might just have that as an excuse to brag about some new shiny material that he thougt fitted into his programming blog but then again. He wouldn't do that, would he?

If anyone is interested I have two links about Svarga.
http://www.scribd.com/doc/31601818/devconf-svarga And
http://svargahq.net/docs/introduction.html

Comment: If you haven't gone too far into that framework, try the Flask framework. It's based upon Jinja2 and Werkzeug, and the documentation is GREAT,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Svarga looks like it's still very, very young. Bleeding-edge software can be cool, but things break. They do. And when Svarga breaks, there is only one person who knows everything about it, and that person can go away, lose interest or just be too busy. Then you're out of luck.

There are also other upsides to using well-known frameworks like Django. For one, there are more extensions, examples and tricks availible, and there are more support options. Django has a bug tracker, IRC channel, lots of knowledgable people on Stack Overflow etcetera, Svarga doesn't have those (yet).

I think that, in the end, it's really about what *you* want. But for some large, important app, I'd recommend against Svarga. For your personal, fun-to-code tool, you should do whatever you like.

Comment: Svarga has an IRC channel. irc://freenode.net/#svarga and a maling list.

Answer (score 0):

> Would you require the framework to
>   have at least semi-good documentation
>   before you thougt It would be worth
>   investing your time in?

I tend to say of course, but otherwise it depends on the size of the framework, readability of the code etc.